# How to create a pie chart circle designs with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, design-patterns, pie-chart

[Here is the problem,How to create this design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFd1a.png)
[Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkwes.png)

Tried experimenting with changing colors,radius still didnt get the design right,
and to get the design i tried all sorts of things to get it perfect but it still always end up getting a wrong design

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
 
colors = ['r','w','r','w','r','w','r','w','r','w','r','w','r','w','r','w','r','w','r','w']
labels = np.ones(20)         
#labels = [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,.........,1.0]
plt.pie([1], colors="k", radius = 2.05)
plt.pie(labels, colors=colors, radius = 2.0)

 
plt.pie([1],colors="g", radius = 1.8)
plt.pie([1], colors="y", radius = 1.6)
plt.pie([1], colors="c", radius = 1.3)
plt.pie([1], colors="b", radius = 1.1)
plt.pie([1], colors="m", radius = 0.9)
plt.pie([1], colors="b", radius = 0.3)

plt.pie(labels, colors=colors, radius = 0.25)
 
plt.pie([1], colors="w", radius = 0.2)
plt.pie([1], colors="k", radius = 0.1)
 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please post code as text not images.

Comment: How do i show the design that i need with text, i am sorry i am new here

Comment: The design is not code, so it can stay as an image, but in your second link you have code. Don't share that code as in image, share it as text.

Comment: you can see the code now, its just an example, i  need the code which can create that black and white stripe circle design

Comment: it will also be appreciated if you can also explain the code, i am a complete beginner in programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a pie chart, you can pass it a colors argument, which it will cycle through. If you give it `["w", "k"]` it will alternate white and black and if you give it `["k", "w"]` it will alternate black and white. So, we can loop through different radii and keep reversing the colors to create the pattern you want.

I've put in lots of comments to explain the code to you, but you should be aware that what I show is way more comments than would be put in a normal program. In reality, comments should only be used to explain code where necessary. If someone is familiar with a library, such as matplotlib and numpy, I wouldn't explain the basic functions as I do in the code below.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# creates the figure
plt.figure()

# creates an all black pie chart (this is used for the black border)
plt.pie([1], colors="k", radius = 2.05)

# colors for the pie slices
colors = ["w", "k"]
stripes = 20    # number of stripes/slices

# data to be plotted; they're all 1s, so it will make them all equally-sized
# slices; makes as many as the stripes variable
data = np.ones(stripes)

# np.arange creates a list of values from the first argument to the second 
# argument with a step size of the last argument
for radius in np.arange(2, 0.01, -0.1):
    plt.pie(data, colors=colors, radius=radius)
    colors = colors[::-1]       # reverse the colors so the stripes alternate
 
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]